# Abstract nonsense proof that stalks of $\mathcal{O}_X$ modules are modules over $\mathcal{O}_X$-stalks

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

> Let $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ be a ringed space and $\mathcal{F}$ be an
>   $O_X$-module. Then for $x \in X$, $\mathcal{F}_x$ has a natural
>   structure of an $O_{X, x}$-module.

**Question:** Is there some abstract nonsense argument how to see that? By that I mean an argument interpreting stalks as direct limits and using their universal properties.

I tried to find one, but usually when one needs a nice description of an action of a ring $R$ on a module $M$, one describes it as a ring homomorphism $R\rightarrow \mathrm{End}_{\mathbb{Z}}(M)$. This seems of no use here, since I cannot see how can something like $\mathrm{End}_\mathbb{Z}(-)$ be used as a functor.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Think in terms of action maps $R \times M \to M$ instead. The categorical point is that taking stalks is a monoidal functor, or something like that.

Comment: If you think in terms of action maps, then the relevant fact is that taking stalks preserves finite limits (in particular finite products).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan  By your comment, I would guess that I should consider some category of ring actions (it's probably clear what I have in mind) and then try to show that direct limits (i.e. the "filtered ones") can be computed "component-wise". Do I understand it correctly?

Comment: @ZhenLin: Now I am a little confused. I don't much understand in what way preserving direct finite products should apply - the only product I see in there is "$R\times M$", but I have trouble seeing it as an actual product in some category (what category would that be?).

Comment: The category of sheaves of sets, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking stalks is a functor, so if a ring $A$ acts on $\mathcal F$, then $A$ acts on the stalk $\mathcal F_x$.

Now if $\mathcal F$ is an $\mathcal O_X$-module, then $A := \mathcal O_X(X)$ acts
on $\mathcal F$.

Applying this with $X$ replaced by a basis of n.h.'s $U$ of $x$, we find that
each $\mathcal O_X(U)$ acts on $\mathcal F_x$, and thus that the stalk $\mathcal O_{X,x}$ does.

Is this nonsensical enough?

Comment: Well, I would guess this is the general approach, but my problem is probably in the step described in the first sentence - seems to me that if one defines action as a ring hom $A \rightarrow \mathrm{End}_\mathbb{Z}(...)$, then the argument would work if $\mathrm{End}_\mathbb{Z}((-)_x)$ was a functor, and not just $(-)_x$.

Comment: @PavelC: By definition, a functor takes morphisms to morphisms (and respects composition, and also addition if it is an additive functor between additive categories, as taking the stalk is), so if you have a homomorphism $A \to End(\mathcal F)$, you get a homomorphism $A \to End(\mathcal F_x)$.